# Encrypting authorization response with state

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

Imagine a `authorization_code flow` which MUST use PAR and after succeded authorization at `authorization_endpoint` instead of returning `code` and `state` returns only `code`, but this response is encrypted with `state` sent earlier in PAR request. Now, if client wan't to verify `state` it have to decrypt response. If client can decrypt response, it means that `state` is valid, otherwise not. This solution allows to verify `state`, but what's more, `code` can't be hijacked even by user that initiated authorization process. Is this a safe and good solution? Or had I not thought about something?

NOTE: In this case, `state` would have to be stored in client session.

Comment: This will work. But the user can still decrypt the authorization code by extracting the state from the client session. The session should be server side.

Comment: Yes, I meant `client session` like it: client (relying party) stores `state` not directly in cookie, but cookie should contain only session identifier (so `state` is stored at server side).